# Bulk / Multiple License purchase

Tags: license, pricing

> Craft CMS Pricing FAQ

https://craftcms.com/pricing

The FAQ mentions discounts when cost is an issue, presumably non-profit sites.

But… is there a discount for bulk purchasing? Example. 10, 50, 100 licenses?

I can't see an 'official' tier for multiple purchase, is it best to ask?

Comment: You should contact the craft support for pricing as they recommend you do in  their FAQ the email is: support@craftcms.com they can help you better and more direct with your question.

Comment: They don't recommend to do that in their pricing FAQ (I linked to it). If they did, I wouldn't post here. Stack Exchange doesn't have any similar question, so this will help others later.

Comment: Actually, the bottom question in the pricing FAQ is "Are any discounts available?" - and the answer is "contact support", as Justin suggests.

Comment: And then it says, "If you would like to use Craft CMS but don’t have the budget for it, please get in touch." It's not a question of enough budget for 1 license. The question is, is there a multiple license discount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is, is there a multiple license discount?

We currently don't have an official policy, but to-date we've handled bulk discount requests on a case-by-case basis.

As the FAQ suggests, contact support@craftcms.com :).

Comment: Thanks Brad. The official line is, 'ask'. Expect an email :)